# Longest Consecutive Sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6

This task is taken from [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/) -

> *Given an unsorted array of integers, find the length of the longest
>   consecutive elements sequence.*
>
> *Your algorithm should run in \$O(n)\$ complexity.*
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Input: [100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2]
>
> Output: 4
>
> /** Explanation: The longest consecutive elements sequence is [1, 2, 3, 4]. Therefore its length is 4. */
> ```

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number}
 */
var longestConsecutive = function(nums) {
  const set = new Set(nums);
  let longestStreak = 1;
  let max = 0;
  set.forEach(x => {
    if (!set.has(x - 1)) {
      let num = x;
      while(set.has(++num)) { ++longestStreak; }
      max = Math.max(max, longestStreak);
      longestStreak = 1;      
    }
  });
  return max;
};
```

Time complexity is \$O(2n)\$ which is still in the range of \$O(n)\$ time complexity.

Comment: To downvoters: please explain your actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` is only used within the `while` loop and not outside of it.
A `for` loop is more appropriate for such pattern.

The solution looks as if you forgot to perform a final refactoring to clean things up.
The function starting with `let longestStreak = 1;` looks like a good idea,
as the exercise is looking for the longest streak, and at this point,
my expectation is that this variable will be probably returned at the end.
But no, to my surprise it is reset to 1 in the `forEach`,
and at the end the function returns `max`.

All that to say, it would make more sense to use a local `length` variable inside the `forEach`, and update `longestStreak` when a higher value is found,
and return it at the end.

```
var longestConsecutive = function(nums) {
  const set = new Set(nums);
  let longestStreak = 0;
  set.forEach(x => {
    if (!set.has(x - 1)) {
      let length = 1;
      for (let num = x + 1; set.has(num); num++) { ++length; }
      longestStreak = Math.max(longestStreak, length);
    }
  });
  return longestStreak;
};
```

Comment: Good point on using the `for`-loop in this case, because it would eliminate the additional `num` variable. I try to use more `while` than `for` loops because `while` loops adds less complexity than `for`-loops.

And creating a new variable, `length`, inside the loop is also a good idea because it makes resetting obsolete. Thanks for your review.